# Unity vr device support

Tags: unity, virtual-reality

I have been looking for a list of VR devices that unity supports (or that you can use to develop VR games with).

However i have been unable to find a list. Currently im looking at **BOBO VR Z4**

But to make sure i do not make any incorrect purchases so it would be really helpful to know supported devices.

Also it is worth noting i'm going to be using the newest version of Unity. (which is currently version 5.6)

Comment: This may be a better question to ask the product's creators directly, eg. on Twitter or via their product support forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling Bobo VR Z4 should be supported via the cardboard platform of unity. (this is just a guess since I didn't test it).

---

The reason why there is no list of devices (but a list of platforms) is that some platforms are open.

The currently supported platforms can be found [here](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/multiplatform/vr-ar)

Occulus Platforms is for the occulus device,
Gear VR is for the gear VR devices
and so on

In short that would be (too) easy.

It gets more complicated with the google familiy of Cardboard and daydream devices. Those platforms are supported by various devices. Some better, some not that good. For daydream also the used smartphone has to support the platform.

A year ago I tested a couple of cardboard headsets and experienced really big differences in the quality of the (same) app (on the same smartphone). The prices have been between 3 Euro and ~ 70 Euro. More expensive isn't actually better.

I used this for my personal vr experiences ([Eimolife Virtual Reality Headset](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81wF1Lb6wRL._SY355_.jpg)). There seem to be a couple of models looking the same with different brand names. But for the price (10 Euro) it was the best choice for me.

When choosing a platform 2 advices:
- Either stick to a closed platform (benefit: all your customers/players will have the same headset = same experience)
- When choosing cardboard: pick a headset where the manufactorer publishes a cardboard profile (the qr code on some of the devices). This allows you to configure cardboard by scanning this qr code and get a good quality visual experience (at least for the part of the cardboard settings).